# how to provide options in json-diff when running from node js program

Tags: json

I am working on a simple JSON comparison code that compares two JSON files.
I found json-diff npm module that does exactly what I want. I want to use it with the -k option (compare only keys). Here is the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

I can do it in the cmd directly using the command:

json-diff a.json b.json -k

But I'm not able to figure out how do I provide the "options" when writing a node js code.

This is what I have tried but it did not work out.

```
var jsonDiff = require('json-diff')
console.log(jsonDiff.diffString({ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, '-k'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the options as the last parameter (*for `.diff` there are 3 parameters*)

```
var jsonDiff = require('json-diff')
console.log(jsonDiff.diff({ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, {keysOnly: true}));
```

For `diffString` there are four params (*the 3rd being the colorize options, and the 4th the options*)

```
var jsonDiff = require('json-diff')
console.log(jsonDiff.diffString({ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, undefined, {keysOnly: true}));
```